# Buggy display when using Ubuntu 15 on virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware, ubuntu-unity

things just sometimes stick and dont display correctly. Ubuntu 15.04 with unity.

examples of faulty screens / displays that just don't seem to refresh correctly:
[image]
[image]

first picture should have looked like this:

[image]

This is really really bad quality. I can't disable 3d acceleration, the apps would become annoyingly slow, unusable.

Is there something I can do?

Change unity with smth else?

pull the plug on virtualbox?

change from virtualbox to vmware?

dualboot?

Comment: Q: What is your physical host's video hardware?  Did you install a corresponding Linux drver?  The screen resolution of your Unity guest?  What OS is your physical host running?

Comment: it's windows 8.1
resolution is up to  1920x1080 I generally use it in windowed mode. It's a intel HD graphic card of an asus notebook. I didn't know I am supposed to install drivers when using Virtualbox?

Comment: it is still buggy, even in full screen mode

Comment: Yes, by all means download the latest Linux Graphics Installer from Intel, and see what it recommends: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Comment: there is no installer for ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i actually ended up using lubuntu install instead, worked better for me. I think there is a known problem with ubuntu 14 and the graphics card